# c++ creating filled sudoku grid from empty matrix of size n

Tags: c++, matrix

I'm trying to write a program that creates a matrix of size N, and puts numbers in so that no numbers repeat in the same column/row using backtracking.

```
1) Put value in cell. If it's a repeat, try a different value.
2) If no such value exists, backtrack 1 cell, and change the value.  //recursive
```

However, the highest number repeats a few times sometimes. E.g:

```
3 1 2     3 1 2 4 5          2 4 1 3 6 5
1 3 3     2 3 1 5 4          4 3 2 5 1 6
2 3 1     1 2 5 3 5 <        1 5 3 2 4 6
          4 5 3 1 2          5 1 6 4 2 3
          5 4 5 2 1 <        6 2 4 1 3 6 <
              ^              3 6 5 6 6 4 <
                                     ^
```

And here's what it's doing:
Once it runs out of numbers to put into a cell (i.e: all restricted, it puts N in)

```
3 1 2 4          3 1 2 4          3 1 2 4          3 1 2 4
1 2 3 0    ->    1 2 3 3    ->    1 2 3 4   ->     1 2 3 4
0 0 0 0          0 0 0 0          0 0 0 0          2 0 0 0
0 0 0 0          0 0 0 0          0 0 0 0          0 0 0 0
```

I'm really stuck here, hopefully someone can find the error in my code:

```
int **grid;                                //2d dynamic array of size 'size'
bool checkRepeat(size,**grid,row,column);  //checks if a number in a column/row is a repeat
int backtrack = 0;
int holder = 0;                            //when backtracking, this holds the number that should be changed


bool checkRepeat(int x, int** grid, int row, int col){
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++){
        if (grid[row][col] == grid[row][i] && col != i){
            return true;
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < x; j++){
        if (grid[row][col] == grid[j][col] && row != j){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main(){
for (int row = 0; row < size; row++){
        for (int col = 0; col < size; col++){

            if (backtrack == 0){
                    grid[row][col] = rand() % size + 1;
            }

            if (backtrack == 1){       //If backtracking, go back one cell.
                grid[row][col] = 0;        //(Since the above for loops went one
                if (col == 0){           //cell forward, go 2 cells back)
                    col = size - 2;
                    row--;
                } else if (col == 1){
                    col = size - 1;
                    row--;
                } else {
                    col-=2;
                }
                holder = grid[row][col];   //put the current number into holder to avoid it
                backtrack = 0;

            }

    /*the following checks if the number in the current cell is
      a repeat and makes sure the number isn't the same as
      before (holder).  Then it checks all possible numbers (1 to size)
      and puts one that matches the rules. If one is not found,
      program backtracks 1 cell*/

            if (checkRepeat(size,grid,row,col) && grid[row][col] > 0){  
                for (int x = 1; x < size+1 && (checkRepeat(x,grid,row,col) || holder == grid[row][col]); x++){

                grid[row][col] = x;
                }
            } 

            if (grid[row][col] == checkRepeat(size,grid,row,col) || grid[row][col] == holder){
                backtrack = 1;        //if no valid number was found in the above
                grid[row][col] = 0;
            }
            holder = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not a direct answer, but perhaps make it impossible to add a duplicate in the first place.

Comment: In general, in backtracking , a copy of the *thing* needs to made and modified, unless it's something as simple as the N-queen problem. YMMV

Comment: Have you tried a recursive solution?  It seems to me like it might be easier to backtrack with recursion.  I'll try to write up something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I may have gone a little overboard on the solution but I thought it was a good challenge for me.  The basic idea is that fill(row, col) is a recursive function.  First it checks the stopping conditions: if the filled-out part of the grid is not valid (a number is repeated in a row or column) it will return false.  It will also return false if there's an attempt to fill outside the grid's size.

If neither stopping condition is met, it will try a value for the grid element and attempt to "fill the rest of the grid" (aka call the fn recursively).  It will do those things as long as the "fill rest" operation fails and it hasn't tried all valid values.  If it has tried all the valid values and the "fill rest" operation still fails, it resets the value to 0.  Finally it returns whether the "fill rest" operation failed or succeeded.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <numeric>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using std::vector;

// helper for std::accumulate
bool logical_and(bool x, bool y) {
  return x & y;
}

class Grid {
public:
  typedef int ElementType;
  typedef vector< vector<ElementType> > GridElements;

  Grid(const int linesize) :
  linesize_(linesize)
  {
    srand(time(NULL));

    // resizes to linesize_ rows & columns, with initial values == 0
    gridElements_.resize(linesize_, vector<ElementType>(linesize_, 0));
  }

  // use like this: cout << grid.to_s();
  std::string to_s() const {
    std::stringstream ss;
    for (int row = 0; row < gridElements_.size(); row++) {
      for (int col = 0; col < gridElements_[row].size(); col++) {
    ss << gridElements_[row][col] << " ";
      }
      ss << std::endl;
    }

    ss << std::endl;

    return ss.str();
  }

  // return true if there are no repeated numbers within filled elements in
  // rows/columns, false otherwise
  bool isValid() const {
    // you would also need to write and call a checkSquare method if you're doing a sudoku puzzle
    for (int i = 0; i < linesize_; i++) {
      if (!isRowValid(i) || !isColValid(i)) {
    return false;
      }
    }

    return true;
  }

  // the recursive function that actually puts values in the grid elements
  // max recursion depth (I think) is linesize_^2
  bool fill(int row, int col) {
    // stopping conditions
    if (!isValid()) {
      return false;
    }
    if ((row == linesize_) || (col == linesize_)) {
      return true;
    }

    int nextCol = (col + 1) % linesize_;
    int nextRow = row;
    if (nextCol < col) {
      nextRow++;
    }

    // keep a record of what numbers have been tried in this element
    vector<bool> attemptedNumbers(linesize_ + 1, false);
    attemptedNumbers[0] = true;

    // We will continue choosing values for gridElements_[row][col]
    // as long as we haven't tried all the valid numbers, and as long as
    // the rest of the grid is not valid with this choice
    int value = 0;
    bool triedAllNumbers = false;
    bool restOfGridValid = false;
    while (!triedAllNumbers && !restOfGridValid) {
      while (attemptedNumbers[value]) {
        value = rand() % linesize_ + 1;
      }
      attemptedNumbers[value] = true;
      gridElements_[row][col] = value;

      // uncomment this for debugging/intermediate grids
      //std::cout << to_s();

      // triedAllNumbers == true if all the numbers in [1, linesize_] have been tried
      triedAllNumbers = std::accumulate(attemptedNumbers.begin(), attemptedNumbers.end(), true, logical_and);
      restOfGridValid = fill(nextRow, nextCol);
    } 
    if (triedAllNumbers && !restOfGridValid) {
      // couldn't find a valid number for this location
      gridElements_[row][col] = 0;
    }

    return restOfGridValid;
  }

private:
  // checks that a number is used only once in the row
  // assumes that values in gridElements_ are in [1, linesize_]
  // return false when the row contains repeated values, true otherwise
  bool isRowValid(int row) const {
    vector<bool> numPresent (linesize_ + 1, false);

    for (int i = 0; i < linesize_; i++) {
      int element = gridElements_[row][i];

      if (element != 0) {
    if (numPresent[element]) {
      return false;
    }
    else {
      numPresent[element] = true;
    }
      }
      // don't do anything if element == 0
    }

    return true;
  }

  // checks that a number is used only once in the column
  // assumes that values in gridElements_ are in [1, linesize_]
  // return false when the column contains repeated values, true otherwise
  bool isColValid(int col) const {
    vector<bool> numPresent (linesize_ + 1, false);

    for (int i = 0; i < linesize_; i++) {
      int element = gridElements_[i][col];

      if (element != 0) {
    if (numPresent[element]) {
      return false;
    }
    else {
      numPresent[element] = true;
    }
      }
      else {
    // if element == 0, there isn't anything left to check, so just leave the loop
    break;
      }
    }

    return true;
  }

  // the size of each row/column
  int linesize_;

  // the 2d array
  GridElements gridElements_;
};


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  // 6x6 grid
  Grid grid(6);

  // pretty sure this is mathematically guaranteed to always return true, assuming the algorithm is implemented correctly ;)
  grid.fill(0, 0);

  std::cout << grid.to_s();
}
```